# python argparser use nargs to capture colon seperated input for a single option

Tags: python

I have below code on a transfer script to capture source and destination, i am successfully able to get the input like this using below cod

`python program -s "source host" "source folder" -d "destination host" "destination folder"`

but i want to change my input some thing like this.

`python program -s "source host:source folder" -d "destination host:destination folder"`

**Below is the code i have used to get the inputs**

```
my_parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='To sync files between source and destination')
my_parser.add_argument('-s',"--source", nargs=2,  help='Enter the source server detail and source folder name')Q
my_parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', nargs=2,  help="Enter the destination server detail")
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    my_parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
clarg = my_parser.parse_args()
```

How can i achieve this. Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just take in 1 argument and split by `:`

```
my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='To sync files between source and destination')
my_parser.add_argument('-s', "--source", help='Enter the source server detail and source folder name')
my_parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination',  help="Enter the destination server detail")
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    my_parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
clarg = my_parser.parse_args()
print(clarg.source.split(":")[0])
print(clarg.source.split(":")[1])
print(clarg.destination.split(':')[0])
print(clarg.destination.split(':')[1])
```

OUTPUT of `python program -s "source host:source folder" -d "destination host:destination folder"`

```
source host
source folder
destination host
destination folder
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `nargs` is the wrong tool here. Instead you need to further process the argument to produce the correct host and folder. You can set a custom function using the `type` argument:

```
import argparse

def host_and_folder(arg):
    try:
        host, folder = arg.split(":")
    except ValueError:
        raise argparse.ArgumentError(None, "Source and Destination details must be in the format host_name:folder_name")
    if not folder:
        folder = "."
    return host, folder

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='To sync files between source and destination')
my_parser.add_argument('-s',"--source", help='Enter the source server detail and source folder name', required=True, type=host_and_folder)
my_parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', help="Enter the destination server detail", required=True, type=host_and_folder)

clarg = my_parser.parse_args()
```

Alternatively you can also specify a custom action and separately set `host` and `folder` as attributes of `source` and `destination`:

```
class HostAndFolderAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        try:
           host, folder = values.split(":")
        except ValueError as e:
           parser.error(f"{self.dest.title()} details must be in the format host_name:folder_name")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, argparse.Namespace(host=host, folder=folder or "."))

my_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='To sync files between source and destination')
my_parser.add_argument('-s',"--source", help='Enter the source server detail and source folder name', required=True, action=HostAndFolderAction, metavar='SOURCE_HOST:[DIRECTORY]')
my_parser.add_argument('-d', '--destination', help="Enter the destination server detail", required=True, action=HostAndFolderAction, metavar='DESTINATION_HOST:[DIRECTORY]')

clarg = my_parser.parse_args(["-s", "foo:temp", "-d", "bar:"])
print(clarg.source.host)
# foo
print(clarg.destination.folder)
# .

clarg = my_parser.parse_args(["-s", "foo:temp", "-d", "bar"])
# usage: ipython3 [-h] -s SOURCE_HOST:[DIRECTORY] -d DESTINATION_HOST:[DIRECTORY]
# error: Destination details must be in the format host_name:folder_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion will try it.